# x86 assembly sys_unlink exit with ENOSYS

Tags: assembly, x86, system-calls

```
;fork
xor eax,eax
mov al,0x2
int 0x80
xor ebx,ebx
cmp eax,ebx
jz wget

;wait(NULL)
xor eax,eax
mov al,0x7
int 0x80

;rm /tmp/pubkey
cdq
push edx
push 0x79656b62
push 0x75702f70
push 0x6d742f2f  
mov ebx,esp
mov al,0xa
int 0x80
```

i have a problem with the above code because the `unlink` syscall exit with `-38 (ENOSYS)`.
The `sys_execve(wget)` (the child) works correctly (the file is downloaded) but unlink doesn't.
I don't understand why i'm getting the ENOSYS error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[wait()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) returns the pid of the child process (or `-1` on error). Since you're not clearing the `AH` register before the next syscall, chances are part of that value is still there, and you end up invoking an arbitrary system call instead of `0x0a`.

Try setting `EAX` instead of `AL`:

```
mov ebx, esp
mov eax, 0x0a
int 0x80
```

Comment: thanks a lot :D you solved my problem! (i used `xor eax,eax` because i don't want null bytes ;) )